# What is wrong with my input for the forfiles -d value?

Tags: powershell

Whenever I enter:

> forfiles /d +10/20/2019 /c "cmd /c echo @FILE last 5 days"

I get an error saying the time setting is wrong. When I change it to something like -50 or -100 it works as its supposed to showing the proper files for those sets of time. I seem to be following the format of mm/dd/year...? I don't know what is wrong. I wanted to list all files that were made within the last 5 or so days. So I basically can't get the longhand date system working.
If I move the /d to after the cmd value does the " move to the end as well like..

> forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @FILE last 5 days /d +10/20/2019"

?

Answer (score 0):

[`forfiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles) is an executable mainly used with cmd.

The problem is in date format. As per `forfiles /?` help, follow "dd.MM.yyyy" format. This might be system locale dependent, so check your installation's help; mine says:

```
/D    date          Selects files with a last modified date greater
                    than or equal to (+), or less than or equal to
                    (-), the specified date using the
                    "dd.MM.yyyy" format; or selects files with a
                    last modified date greater than or equal to (+)
                    the current date plus "dd" days, or less than or
                    equal to (-) the current date minus "dd" days. A
                    valid "dd" number of days can be any number in
                    the range of 0 - 32768.
                    "+" is taken as default sign if not specified.
```

As for a Powershell solution, use `Get-ChildItem` and filter based on `CreationDate`, like so

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | ? {$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)}
```

This will get a directory listing and select files that have creation time greater or equal to a date five days ago.

Comment: "- Selects files with a last modified date later than or equal to (+) or earlier than or equal to (-) the specified date, where Date is in the format MM/DD/YYYY." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Comment: It's not working regardless of what order I go or if I change it to neutral dates like 1/1/2019

Comment: @kite Try dot `.` as separator instead of a slash `/`. Maybe dash `-` works as well?

Comment: no, none of that works. the only thing that doesnt' lead to error is /d -30 or any value where 30 is

Comment: @kite That's unfortunate, as it works on my system. Which locale are you using? Does the native Powershell version work?

Comment: I don't know what any of that means. I'm using windows 8.1, whatever the included powershell is. I tried it using cmd.exe and same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
/d 2019-10-24
```

Works.

/20charactersmoreplzserialdownvotingisbannableoffensemrguyfrommetathread.Ididn'tknowiwasworthit,ty.